# Шаблон сайта с настраиваемыми пользователем полями

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

Есть шаблон сайта, после изменения любых доступных пользователю полей данные должны храниться в базе данных. Количество полей которые добавляет, изменяет пользователь может измениться в будущем.

Как реализовывается подобная структура баз данных, как должен будет взаимодействовать фронт с подобной структурой?

Должен ли фронт добавлять подобные поля делая запрос с указанием имени через бек или это регулируется только беком?

Нужно ли использовать в таком случаи не реляционную базу (из-за ее неконтролируемых полей)?

Comment: "Должен ли фронт добавлять подобные поля делая запрос с указанием имени через бек или это регулируется только беком?" - вопрос бессмысленный.

Comment: " Количество полей которые добавляет, изменяет пользователь может измениться в будущем." - это очень плохая идея, которая всегда очень плохо кончается. Если вы не находитесь в кровной вражде с тем, кто будет этот сайт в дальнейшем сопровождать, то делать это не стоит. Впрочем, если находитесь, то тоже не стоит

Comment: Возможно, формулировка так себе, но эту часть вопроса можно переворулировать как "давать ли возможность изменения структуры базы непосредственно из фронт- приложения, или это должен белать бэк"

Comment: что значит "должен делать бэк"? По своему желанию, в 12 часов ночи, случайным образом добавлять два поля к БД и удалять пять?

Comment: @S.H. Спасибо за конкретную формулировку. Примерно подобная проблема и появилась. Знаю что нарушает множество концепций управления баз данных со стороны фронта. Но если пользователю дадут возможность изменить, создать десятки страниц, как их собирать, и где их хранить? База данных будет  доступна только пользователю и не кому более. Все его действия будут ломать только его сайт

Comment: для начала надо объяснить всему миру, что такое "поля" и "страницы". И какое это все имеет отношение к "реляционным БД". Желательно с конкретными примерами, а не просто делать неопределенные жесты руками

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Здесь есть несколько подходов.

Для того,  чтобы было весело - я постараюсь описать их коротко и используя аналогии.

1. "всем всем всем можно делать всё-всё-всё".

Этот подход используется, грубо говоря, в GraphQL - короче, Вы из js просто можете делать всё, что угодно, с базой данных.

Правда, предполагается, что код, который работает с базой, всё таки работает на стороне сервера.

Иногда - когда он попадаетна сторону клиента - какой нибудь школьник, который умеет нажимать F12 в барузере и знает команду DROP - может дропнуть Вашу базу...

2. Подход nongoDB.

Этот тот самый "нереляционный" подход. mongoDB ориенирована на храниение "документов"- грубо говоря, готовых и сложных по своей структуре json'чиков. Это позволяет не думать об отдельных полях, а работать с ними по принципу "я тут завел поле - а оно автоматически появится в базе данных"

Правда, при этом у вас реализуется только сохраниние и показ этого поля. Довольно беполезно, если Вы захотите о ээтому полю делать фильтр и т.п.

3. Подход CMS, реализованных на базе релационных баз.

Это самый сложный и самый проработанный подход. Грубо говоря, у вас есть на back'е скрипты, котрые действительно позволяют определять разные новые объекты, класть их в базу данных в виде отдельных таблиц, описывать связи между ними, и делать поиск по значениям полей в этих таблицах.

Это не просто, но хорошо формализуемо из за многолетней истории развития реляционных бз данных и отработатнности моделей, используемых там.

Что еще посоветовать? Предлагаю начать с мысленного эксперимента: вот Вы начинаете расширять те объекты, котрые у Вас есть. Вы можете добавить туда текстовое поле, и захотеть поиск по нему. Можете добавить числовое поле или поле даты - тогда вы захотите сделать одновременно поиск по диапазоеу значений. А можете добавить поле с перечислимым типом, отдельным случаем которого является логическое поле.

Также, пользователь может захотеть удалить или переименовать поле.

Если Вы смоежете решить эти здачи - то бОльшая часть "хотелок" относительно добавления новых полей будет решена.

Comment: Что такое "Иногда код для работы с базой попадает на сторону клиента"?

Comment: @Ипатьев - ну, формально никто не бъет по рукам, если человек напишет js, в котором определит коннекшн стринг с базой данных, откроет её наружу для доступа с любых адресов и будет просто в js определять SQL запросы и фигачить их в базу. но это, мягко говоря, "небезопасно"

Comment: @Ипатьев - я сам вижу в своём ответе много пробелов. Я готов его убрать, если вместо него кто то напишет ответ получше. Это подводит наск флософскому вопросу: что лучше - посредственный по своему качеству ответ или отсутствие ответа...

Comment: Работал с GraphQl через ноду. Там ограничены actions, их задает только бэк. Мб в  php возможно дропнуть базу, но с Node такое не наблюдалось

Comment: @Locker - Вы правы, но нода и GraphQL - штуки гораздо более современные, и разрабатывались с большой оглядкой на используемые практики. В то же время попортить записи в базе через него ничто не помешает.